# How do I force git submodules to be present and commited in the main repository?

Tags: git

Is it possible to add Git submodules files and to commit them to my root git module?

I deeply searched and never found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do such a thing, you are better off using git subtrees instead of git submodules, that way the external code is part of your main repository.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible using submodules.

But a repository can be cloned with its submodules [using the `--recursive` flag to `git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> --recursive
> --recurse-submodules
>
> After the clone is created, initialize all submodules within, using their default settings. This is equivalent to running `git submodule update --init --recursive` immediately after the clone is finished. This option is ignored if the cloned repository does not have a worktree/checkout (i.e. if any of `--no-checkout`/`-n`, `--bare`, or `--mirror` is given)

Many projects instruct users to clone using this flag in their README, getting started guide, or elsewhere.